# jquery fancybox content click issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've a website and use the fancybox in the following way:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Fancybox
    $("#lightbox").fancybox({
        closeBtn : false,
    });
}); 

function openLightBox(){
    $('#lightbox').click();
}
```

I've set the lightbox to be hidden from css and when I click on the menu item it opens the lightbox
Login

The fancybox opens just fine but when I try to click on the content inside the block it behaves strange and triggers another click event on it.
You can see the issue accessing the following [link](http://govarchives.com/test/) and clicking on the bottom menu item 'Secure Login' and then clicking somewhere inside the lightbox content.

Could anyone tell me how to fix that issue?
Thanks

Comment: your making the call to fancybox too compliated on the website... give me a minute to show you in an answer!

Comment: the issue is that the selector `#lightbox` is bound to fancybox but it's also the target of fancybox. In other words, that selector is the trigger and the target. You need another selector to fire fancybox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your site, you are calling fancybox using:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openLightBox();">Secure Login</a></li>
```

Which links to a function called openLightBox():

```
function openLightBox(){
    $('#lightbox').click();
```

And you also use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fancybox
    $("#lightbox").fancybox({
        closeBtn : false,
    });
});
```

These are all unnecessary. All you need in the first `<li>` is an id and use the `href` to link to the `<div id="lightbox">`, which you can then use to call fancybox:

```
<li><a href="#lightbox" id="linky">Secure Login</a></li>
```

Then all you need to do is set up fancybox to act on this id:

```
$("#linky").fancybox();
```

You put any settings you want to use in the above so for example:

```
$("#linky").fancybox({
    'width' : '90%',
    'height' : '90%'
```

});

This is where you put the code to remove the close button.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giovanni1983/QzKRW/) for an example using snippets of your code (i havent hidden the lightbox div but you do that the same way as you have been: in CSS)
Thats all there is to it!

Comment: thanks a lot for the descriptive answer which left no more questions and solved my problem

Comment: I've taken much more from this site than I've given so I'm glad I could help!